# Initializing arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to initialize the last element in the array

> int grades[10];

to grade 7 but it doesn't seem to work

I'm using C++ btw

Comment: @JohnHemmars: since you're new to C++, sometimes your notion of certain things ("last element" in your case) doesn't coincide with the common one.  Please, try posting more complete examples, preferably the ones that can be copy-pasted and immediately compiled.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to initialize them all at definition:

```
int grades[10] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7 };
```

If you want to initialize after:

```
int grades[10];
grades[9] = 7;
```

But, be aware that grades 0..8 will still be uninitialized, and will likely be junk values.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that the ninth element was the last one =) thank you

Comment: if you were assigning to grades[10] that's called an "off by one" error.  That is memory that grades doesn't own and you may have corrupted something else in the function/program.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

Comment: yeah thank you very much, I knew about this but I've never really used it while coding.. 

I won't forget it from now on!

Comment: You're incorrect in that the "ninth" one is last. If you have ten elements, the tenth one is the last one. The thing is that they are numbered 0 through 9, so your tenth element is accessed by the number 9.

Comment: @tfinniga: You mean _definition_, not _declaration_, since `int grades[10];` _defines_ the array.

Answer (score 4):

One more thing, if you initialize only the first element (if explicit array size is specified) or a shorter initiliazation list, the unspecified elements are fill with 0. E.g.

```
int grades[10] = {8}; //init with one element
```

is the same as:

```
int grades[10] = { 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

or

```
int grades[10] = { 1, 9, 6, 16 }; //or init with a shorter than array size list with a minimum of 1 element
```

is the same as:

```
int grades[10] = { 1, 9, 6, 16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

I find it handy for initializing an array with 0 values.

```
float coefficients[10] = {0.0f}; //everything here is full of 0.0f
```

Comment: Note that it is valid C++ to write: `int a[10] = {};`.

Comment: I would be careful about assuming the contents of an array will be zeroed by default.  This is compiler and platform specific.

Answer (score 4):

when You write something like

```
int a[5] = {0};
```

it sets the whole array to zero on the contrary

```
int a[5] = {3};
```

sets only the first element and the rest may be anything(garbage values);

if You want to set the whole array with some value then u can go for the

```
std :: fill()
```

something like this

```
std::fill(arr, arr+100, 7); // sets every value in the array to 7
```

and if there is a character array You can always go for the `memset` function

Answer (score 1):

The last element is `grades[9]`, since arrays in C++ are zero-based (e.g. `grades[0]` to `grades[9]` are 10 elements).  Is that what you're doing?

You might need to subtract one from the grade to use as your subscript value, or set the extent to one more.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that an array with ten elements will have grades[0] through grades[9], and that grades[10] is an error.